# How many Map tasks in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, reduce

Hi guys I got 2 questions where I dont know what happens, and I dont got a system to test it on:

1. I have a directory containing 4 files where 1 of the files is empty. How many Map tasks do I get from Hadoop Map Reduce when those 4 files are the input.
2. I got a directory with 4 subfolders including 3 files (one folder is empty) how many map tasks do I get from Hadoop Map Reduce, when the parent folder is the input in my Map Reduce program?

**
In all my questions the files are smaller than the block-size.

Answer (score 0):

1. 4 mappers (splitter doesn't care if one file is empty or not)
2. 3 * 3 = 9 mappers (empty folder doesn't contain any file = no mappers for that)

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop MR job will spawn number of mappers based on number of blocks/input split you have for the job.
In this case, as you assume that file size is less than block size then there will only be 1block for each file

Formula : `Number of Mapper : Number of input splits`

For 1: You supply 4 files to MR job . This means MR job has to read 4blocks , so it will spawn 4 Mappers. These 4 Mappers can run all in parallel or one by one or two at a time depending on your Cluster hardwares.

NOTE: InputSplitter will not consider the fact that file is empty or not. It will spawn 1 mapper for empty file as well

For 2:   You supply 3 files in total (empty subfolder do not count). So your MR job will spawn 3 Mapper.

Hope this helps you.